# Is there a tm_text function argument to control orientation of the text

Tags: r, tmap

This concerns plotting text on linestrings. I would like to get the tm_text orientation to be along the direction of the underlying shape (linestring) direction.

I looked in the documentation of tm_text, but I do not see anything related to orientation of the text with respect to underlying (digitized direction) linestring.

For example, if there is a line_AB, I would like the text is aligned in the direction of AB, starting from A and towards B. Similarly, if the underlying linestring is going from B to A that is line_BA, then the text should start from B  and go towards A. The placement of the text can still be as it is now in the middle of the linestring.

Please guide if this is possible with tmap?

[image]